# Testing for membership in a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I know the `current_user`'s answers because the `User` model has an `answers` collection:

```
current_user.answers
```

How do I test whether that `answers` collection contains the current answer (referenced by the `@answer` class variable) at each step of a loop?

**I was tempted to use the include? method:**

```
current_user.answers.include?(@answer)
```

**but I see it's for mixins :(**

Comment: What do you mean you "see `include?` is for mixins"? It's the normal way to do this.

Comment: @Chuck - I meant that I was reading about include? and it said it's for modules not for collections. So if you want to test whether a class includes a particular module you would use include? I'm not sure how it's also possible to use it with a collection.

Comment: Joe, you may be getting confused with the 'included' callback method of ruby's Module class (or the include statement). Your code as shown would work fine, though the 'exists?' method as outlined below by cwninja is easier on the database and is preferable in this use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Enumerable collections (including Arrays, Hashes and Sets) have the `include?` method to test membership.

```
[1,2,3].include? 2 # => true
{foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'}.include? :foo # => true
[1,2,3].include? 5 # => false
```

(There's also an `include?` method that modules have, but it's not the same thing.)

Comment: Chuck: Thanks for clarifying the distinction.

Answer (score 3):

You may be best off doing this in the database:

```
current_user.answers.exists?(@answer.id)
```

This will execute a `select id from answers where id = ? and user_id = ?` and return `true` if it exists.

If you already have answers loaded in memory, `include?` should work, or `any?{|ans| ans.id == @answer.id}` or flatten them all out into a set of ids outside the loop:

```
Set.new(current_user.answers.map(&:id)
```

and then test for id inclusion inside the loop.